# MySQL Query takes time to execute

Tags: mysql, time, execution

The queries are as simple as that:

```
Eg 1: "UPDATE threads SET hits = hits+1 WHERE id = TID"
Eg 2: "UPDATE users SET last_activity = unix_timestamp() WHERE id = UID"

`users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_activity` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

`threads` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hits` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Let's take this query as example:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET last_activity = unix_timestamp() WHERE id = UID");
```

without the query, script takes ~30 ms to execute:

[image]

with the query, script takes ~110 ms to execute:

[image]

Best regards, Duluman Edi

LE: The code that generates the execution time is the following:

```
///this is placed above any code
$mtime = explode(' ',microtime()); 
$mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0]; 
$tstart = $mtime;
.....
my game code is here
.....
$mtime = explode(' ',microtime());
echo lang('info','page_load').' '.number_format(($mtime[1] + $mtime[0]) -    $tstart,4,'.','')*1000;
```

This is how I calculate the execution time, and it's pretty accurate, never failed me.
P.S. - The real execution time is about 15 ms lower, because I'm hosting this on Windows at the moment.

Comment: Show the code that is generating the ms timestamp.

Comment: `WHERE tid = TID` looks fishy. Do you have a `tid` column?

Comment: @ypercube, Sorry, misspelled, where id = TID is correct.

Comment: @PenguinCoder, I added the code that calculates the execution time.

Comment: How many records are there in `users`?

Comment: @edduvs: are you using `mysql_connect` or `mysql_pconnect`? Is the database server running on the same host?

Comment: @Quassnoi , yes, I'm running a XAMPP server on windows, and I use mysql_connect , my first thought was about Windows platform, but I tried it on Linux too, and it does the same thing.

Comment: @edduvs: please replace your `UPDATE` query with `SELECT 1` and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Your `$mtime` initialization is at the beginning of the page, and not at the beginning of the SQL Query statement? So you're measuring complete script execution, not SQL query execution...

Comment: @PenguinCoder, yes the milliseconds are for the whole script. But, if you want the time specifically, I can show you the time execution from phpMyAdmin. Because the screens are on the very same page, so it's just the SQL SYNTAX which is doing the difference
----------------------

1 row affected. ( Query took 0.1174 sec )
UPDATE users SET last_activity = UNIX_TIMESTAMP( ) WHERE id =1, which means 113 milliseconds. So my script was pretty accurate.

Comment: @Qassnoi what do you mean by SELECT 1 ? A simple query ? it takes 0.0002 sec (0.2 milliseconds)

Comment: @edduvs: is there any other activity on the database server? Is `users` udpated by any other process? What happens if you update `username` rather than `last_activity`?

Comment: How fast does `SELECT hits FROM threads WHERE id = TID` (and does it return 1 row)?

Comment: @ypercube it takes 0.0003 sec and returns one row.
It's just related to that UPDATE statement.. and I don't know why.

Comment: @Quassnoi , your statement takes 0.0648 sec which I'm ok with.

Comment: @edduvs: do you have any triggers defined on `users`? What happens if you update `last_activity` with a constant rather than `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: Did you already try `REPAIR TABLE`?

Comment: @Quassnoi , same thing even if it's constant or unix_timestamp()

Comment: @Kaii there's nothing wrong with the table, but even though I tried it at your request, same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I could make an ajax call on $(document).ready() to make this changes after page loads, because this UPDATE statement is quite nested up.

Comment: This will not reduce the query time... Just differ the load time, and if PHP sessions are used, the session would only unlock after, which would block the user to do anything meanwhile...

Comment: I never said it reduces anything, just that I can "work around" that query time. So please stop downvoting before understanding what I write

Answer (score 0):

Could you please make sure that your `id` column is an `index`? Or `primary key`... This will make your query lighting fast.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uid ON users
```